# TensorBoard does not show images

Tags: tensorflow, firefox, tensorboard

I am running this code to practice the tensor-board :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()   # To clear the defined variables and operations of the previous cell

# create the variables
w_gs = tf.get_variable('W_Grayscale', shape=[30, 10], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=1))
w_c = tf.get_variable('W_Color', shape=[50, 30], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0, stddev=1))

# ___step 0:___ reshape it to 4D-tensors
w_gs_reshaped = tf.reshape(w_gs, (3, 10, 10, 1))
w_c_reshaped = tf.reshape(w_c, (5, 10, 10, 3))

# ____step 1:____ create the summaries
gs_summary = tf.summary.image('Grayscale', w_gs_reshaped)
c_summary = tf.summary.image('Color', w_c_reshaped, max_outputs=5)

# ____step 2:____ merge all summaries
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

# create the op for initializing all variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# launch the graph in a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ____step 3:____ creating the writer inside the session
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)
    # initialize all variables
    sess.run(init)
    # ____step 4:____ evaluate the merged op to get the summaries
    summary = sess.run(merged)
    # ____step 5:____ add summary to the writer (i.e. to the event file) to write on the disc
    writer.add_summary(summary)
    print('Done writing the summaries')
```

**Browsers:  FireFox, google chrome
System  : Ubuntu 18.0.4
Tensorboard:1.9.0 (conda version)
**

This code does not show any images and on the terminal, I get this error:

**W1205 14:01:28.782797 Thread-4 application.py:300] path /[[getCompareSeqImageSrc(seqfeat.name, seqNumber)]] not found, sending 404**

Comment: If you want to show images on TB, don't you want `tf.summary.image`?

Comment: @ShlomiF, yes sure. I used `tf.summary.image`